# Unable to form the proper Linq query using an "IN" list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below SQL Query

```
;with cte as(
select a.* 
from [dbo].[AccountViewModel] a
where a.COLLECTORID = 724852
and a.MONTH = 12
and a.YEAR=2015)

select *
from cte c
where c.DispCode in ('Deceased','DND','WN','WI','NC','NORESPONSE','SKIP','SHIFTED','SFU')
OR (c.DispCode in('PTP','DIB','WCE','DP') and convert(varchar(11), c.PTPDate) >=convert(varchar(11), getdate()))
OR (MONTH(c.LastPaymentDate) = 12 and YEAR(c.LastPaymentDate)=2015)
```

I need to convert this into an equivalent Linq query (C#).

The Cte part is working fine with the below program (I have cross checked the records)

```
private List<AccountViewModel> GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents()
        {
            var allAcountsForLoggedInAgents = new List<AccountViewModel>();

           allAcountsForLoggedInAgents = new ViewModelDatabase()
                    .Accounts
                    .Where(a =>
                                a.COLLECTORID == 724852 && 
                                a.MONTH == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                                a.YEAR == DateTime.Now.Year
                          )
                    .ToList();

            return allAcountsForLoggedInAgents;
        }
```

However the part outside CTE is not working correctly (means improper records)

```
GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents()
.Where
(
    a =>
      ("Deceased,DND,WN,WI,NC,NORESPONSE,SKIP,SHIFTED,SFU".Split(',').Any(x => x.Contains(a.DispCode)))
      || ("PTP,DIB,WCE,DP".Split(',').Any(b => b.Contains(a.DispCode)) && a.PTPDate >= DateTime.Now)
      || (a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Month == 12 && a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Year == 2015)
)
```

I believe that may be I am using "ANY" in a wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This condition is not the same as the `IN` clause

```
("Deceased,DND,WN,WI,NC,NORESPONSE,SKIP,SHIFTED,SFU".Split(',').Any(x => x.Contains(a.DispCode)))
```

because it searches `a.DispCode` in one of the strings. You should use equality instead:

```
("Deceased,DND,WN,WI,NC,NORESPONSE,SKIP,SHIFTED,SFU".Split(',').Any(x => x == a.DispCode))
```

This is not ideal, because `Split` operation is not free, so you don't want to do it as part of your query. Making a `static` array of strings:

```
static readonly string[] DispCodeFilter = new string[] {
    "Deceased", "DND", "WN", "WI", "NC", "NORESPONSE", "SKIP", "SHIFTED", "SFU"
};
...
(DispCodeFilter.Any(x => x == a.DispCode))
```

Comment: thanks Sir, solution worked...i m doing some more testing and then ll accept

Comment: Sir, just 1 thing to ask, so the same i need to do for ("PTP,DIB,WCE,DP".Split(',').Any(b => b.Contains(a.DispCode))  ?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Yes, you need to do the similar for the other `IN` condition

Answer (score 1):

Your In condition is incorrect.  It can be fixed by adding an extension method.  I am using a generic method, but you could make it type specific if you only need/want it for strings.  I am using params, so you can either provide the items one by one or via a split.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] items) {
        return items.Any(i=> Equals(item, i));
}

GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents().Where( a => a.DispCode.In
  ("Deceased","DND","WN","WI","NC","NORESPONSE","SKIP","SHIFTED","SFU")
     ||  (a.DispCode.In("PTP,DIB,WCE,DP".Split(',')) &&
          a.PTPDate >= DateTime.Now)
     || (a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Month == 12 && a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Year == 2015)
```

)

One difference between this and the sql version, and a reason you may not want it to be generic, is that it is case sensitive: "wi" doesn't equal "WI".

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 simple rules for converting SQL to Linq

```
SQL             Linq  
============    ==========
IN (...)        Contains
EXISTS (...)    Any
```

where `Contains` is the corresponding `Enumerable/Queryable` method (not to be mixed with `string.Contains`).

According to this, your Linq criteria should be something like this

```
var DispCodes1 = new [] { "Deceased", "DND", "WN", "WI", "NC", "NORESPONSE", "SKIP", "SHIFTED", "SFU" };
var DispCodes2 = new [] { "PTP", "DIB", "WCE", "DP" };

GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents()
.Where
(
    a =>
      DispCodes1.Contains(a.DispCode)
      || (DispCodes2.Contains(a.DispCode)) && a.PTPDate >= DateTime.Now)
      || (a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Month == 12 && a.LastPaymentDate.Value.Year == 2015)
)
```

[dasblinkenlight answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347792/could-not-able-to-form-the-proper-linq-query/34347829#34347829) contains a good point, so you can make `DispCodes1` and `DispCodes2` static, but that's not essential.

Another thing to mention is that the way you did the "CTE part" is not equivalent to the SQL query, where `cte` is just a named subquery and the whole query executes in the database, while in your implementation the `cte` part is executed in the database, then gets materialized in the memory and the additional query is executed in the memory using Linq To Objects. To make it fully equivalent and let the whole query execute in the database, change the `GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents` result type to `IQueryable<AccountViewModel>` and remove `ToList` call.